# Is it possible to style the Facebook Registration/Login Plugin?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Or is it possible to write my own? I have the skill to write my own, just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style the login button. It has to be the facebook one. The same thing applies to facebook like buttons. Source will come soon

Comment: Okay, excluding the buttons, would it be possible emulating the registration feature of Facebook's plugin (that is obviously given to people who don't want to do the coding themselves) in my own website?

Comment: I am assuming it is possible (you want to write something that would be equivalent to a `FB.Login` call correct?). I am not really sure how you would want to approach that though. I guess you could start trying figure out how their `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` calls work. Those are what they use to load in all their scripts allowing them to use these login calls